# Extracting values from a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please I tried getting the values imputed by the user but when I input the value and cluck submit, the page reloads without showing the values. any help please. Thank you

```
var body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.style.width = '100px';
tbl.style.border = '2px solid yellow';
var n = 10
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    var td = tr.insertCell(0);
    var tf = tr.insertCell(0);
    var input = document.getElement('input');
    input.name = "input2";
    input.id = "input2";
    input.value = "";
    var clone = input.cloneNode();
    clone.name = "input1";
    clone.id = "input1";
    td.appendChild(clone);
    tf.appendChild(input);
    td.style.border = '2px solid  yellow';
    tf.style.border = '2px solidyellow';
}
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.appendChild(tbl);
body.appendChild(form);
var submit = document.createElement("input");
submit.type = "submit";
Submit.on click = 'show()'

function show() {
    var c = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    document.write(c.value);
}
form.appendChild(submit)
tableCreate();
var c = document.getElementById("input2");
document.write(c);
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to display the values before the submit? Do you want to submit the values and be able to use them later?...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think doing things like `myElement.onclick='show()'` makes sense, since you are doing things in JS anyway. Why not just add an event listener to the form, which would listen for submit? Preventing the default action (which includes refreshing the page) should be what you are looking for, if I got you correctly.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- prevents page reload
    // 
    // Here goes your code, that should
    // execute when the form is submitted
});
```

**EDIT:**
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4jbdebb/). Enter some values, press submit and then check your console. You will see 2 arrays - one with the left values, one with the right ones.

Comment: Yea, it stopped reloading, but its still not show the values I inputed

Comment: @chika Could you tell me, what are you trying to get? I did fix a couple of mistakes, while looking through the code, but I'm still not sure, about some things. For exmaple, you create 10 elements with the same id, while id should be unique in the context of a page. What values are you trying to get?

Comment: Thank you....I jux removed the function show() and it started giving the values. About the unique ids.... What I want is to be able to extract all the values that will be imputed by the user. I don't know how to assign the unique values and display all of them when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: @chika Check my answer, I added  a JSfiddle.

Comment: Tank u bro, it worked. Now, I tried adding a for loop insideinside the event listener but it only iterates once instead of the number of times the usa wants. This z the code                form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- prevents page reload
    // 
    // Here goes your code, that should
    // execute when the form is submitted
   for (var r = 0; r < n; r++) {
   var c =document.getElementById("inputa0").value;
   var d =document.getElementById("inputb2").value;
   f=+c+ +d
   document.write(f)
   document.write(c)
   }
   
});

Comment: And please, I need all the imputed value to be saved with a unique variable name . thank you as you help